# PHP - Get value from webhook from go high level

Tags: php

this is the value I'm getting from go high level

```
2022-11-27 07:48:30 {
    "contact_id":"hfjdkleidhfjruth",
    "first_name":"My First Name",
    "last_name":"My Last Name",
    "full_name":"My Name",
    "email":"email@email.com",
    "phone":"+12345678"
}
```

How can I get the value inside that and display it using php?

I tried

```
$WebHook = '2022-11-27 07:48:30{"contact_id":"hfjdkleidhfjruth","first_name":"My First Name","last_name":"My Last Name","full_name":"My Name","email":"email@email.com","phone":"+12345678"}';

echo $WebHook['2022-11-27 07:48:30']['first_name'];
```

Comment: is that a json ?

Comment: It looks like JSON with a debug message in front of it. That makes it just invalid and impossible to work with in an easy way.